# string.join(list) on object array rather than string array

Tags: python, string, list

In Python, I can do:

```py
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
', '.join(list)    # 'a, b, c'
```

However, if I have a list of objects and try to do the same thing:

```
class Obj:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'name'

list = [Obj(), Obj(), Obj()]
', '.join(list)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, instance found
```

Is there any easy way? Or do I have to resort to a for-loop?

Answer (score 489, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension or a generator expression instead:

```
', '.join([str(x) for x in list])  # list comprehension
', '.join(str(x) for x in list)    # generator expression
```

Comment: or a generator expression: ', '.join(str(x) for x in list)

Comment: any idea on which of them would be faster?

Comment: My experiments says that the list comprehension one can be a good 60% faster on small lists (experiment run 10^6 times on a list of three object()s). However, their performance is similar on big lists (2nd experiment run once on a 10^7 objects() list).

Comment: for a good 30% speed-up (over generator expression above), one can use the supposedly less readable `map` expression (below).

Comment: This answer is objectively worse than the `map` solution.

Comment: Should not use str, should instead use .encode('utf-8')

Answer (score 107):

The built-in string constructor will automatically call `obj.__str__`:

```
''.join(map(str,list))
```

Comment: map() doesn't change the list, it's equivalent to [str(o) for o in list]

Comment: +1: Map is a good approach; "changing the list" isn't an accurate comment.

Comment: (another) +1.. map is not less readable, just need to know what the map function does

Comment: Be aware that map does make pylint complain (as does a lot of things but..), it's prefered to use list comprehension because map has been superseded by list comprehension and it's more pythonic.

Comment: @Michael Not correct. `reduce` was the one that was removed, because it usually left people guessing and thus wasn't "pythonic". `map` on the other hand is not an issue.

Comment: @PascalvKooten - I was refering to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569134/why-doesnt-pylint-like-built-in-functions and map definitely generates pylint warnings for me.

Comment: @Michael Ah my bad, I somehow missed that you were talking in "pylint's name".

Comment: (another) +1: coming from the Perl world this is the most common thing in the universe: join("sep", list) - and all elements of list get converted to their string representations. I've been really struggling to find a solution in python.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a super old post, but I think what is missed is overriding `__repr__`, so that `__repr__ = __str__`, which is the accepted answer of this [question marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448175/confused-about-str-on-list-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

another solution is to override the join operator of the str class.

Let us define a new class my_string as follows

```
class my_string(str):
    def join(self, l):
        l_tmp = [str(x) for x in l]
        return super(my_string, self).join(l_tmp)
```

Then you can do

```
class Obj:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'name'

list = [Obj(), Obj(), Obj()]
comma = my_string(',')

print comma.join(list)
```

and you get

```
name,name,name
```

BTW, by using **list** as variable name you are redefining the list class (keyword) ! Preferably use another identifier name.

Hope you'll find my answer useful.

Comment: Never do that, defining your own classes for builtin types makes your code really hard to integrate

Answer (score 0):

Not `str.join` but you can also use `str.format` to join the objects into a single string, especially if `__str__` method is defined and `lst` is not very long.

```py
class Obj:
    def __str__(self):
        return "name"

lst = [Obj(), Obj(), Obj()]
"{}, {}, {}".format(*lst)    # 'name, name, name'
```

If `lst` is very long and initializing specific number of placeholders is not feasible, then we can initialize a string of placeholders and format it afterwards (admittedly, very ugly though).

```py
(len(lst)*"{}, ").format(*lst).rstrip(', ')
```