# Why doesn't Pylint like built-in functions?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, pylint

I have a line like this:

```
filter(lambda x: x == 1, [1, 1, 2])
```

Pylint is showing a warning:

```
W:  3: Used builtin function 'filter'
```

Why is that? is a list comprehension the recommended method?

Of course I can rewrite this like this:

```
[x for x in [1, 1, 2] if x == 1]
```

And I get no warnings, but I was wondering if there's a PEP for this?

Comment: Funnily, pylint doesn't like when I use the builtin function `map`, but it doesn't like either when I import the `map` function from `cytoolz` to use this instead.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Pylint often chatters on about stuff it shouldn't. You can disable the warning in a .pylintrc file.

This page http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0141 indicates the problem is that filter and map have been superseded by list comprehensions.

A line like this in your pylintrc file will quiet the warning:

```
disable=W0141
```

Comment: I didn't know about it either.  I ran pylint with the "-i y" flag to include the message number, then I Googled "pylint W0141", and that's what I found.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: Thank you! You should eventually also add the header `[MESSAGES CONTROL]` (see [.pylintrc example](http://www.pymvpa.org/misc/pylintrc)) as somebody who just creates this file mgiht not know that this is necessary.

Comment: Consider disabling this by using the longer, more readable message name: `# pylint: disable=bad-builtin`.  Or in the pylintrc: `[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=bad-builtin`.  It's more clear that just a warning number.

Answer (score 11):

> Why is that? is a list comprehension the recommended method?

List comprehension is recommended in [the tutorial example](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which states

> it’s more concise and readable.

and by most answerers on SO's [Python List Comprehension Vs. Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map/6407222#6407222) where [it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6407222/1587329)

1. *more efficient* to use list comprehension than `filter` if you are defining a `lambda` each time
2. maybe *more readable* (and with similar efficiency) to use `filter` if the function is pre-defined
3. necessary to use `filter` and `map` if you

   - map `map`,
   - curry `map`, or
   - use functional programming

TL;DR: use list comprehension in most cases

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem and could not figure out

why the built-in function `input' is bad. I you intend

to disable it:

> pylint --bad-functions="[map,filter,apply]" YOUR_FILE_TO_CHECK_HERE

Once you like the settings:

```
pylint --bad-functions="[map,filter,apply]" --some-other-supercool-settings-of-yours
--generate-rcfile > test.rc
```

Verify that your settings are in the file, e.g.:

```
cat test.rc | grep -i YOUR_SETTING_HERE
```

After that you can use this file locally

```
pylint --rcfile test.rc --your-other-command-line-args ...
```

or even use it as your default rcfile. For this I kindly refer you to

```
pylint --long-help
```

Comment: In python2, `input()` is evil because it does `eval(raw_input())`. You should always use `raw_input()`. In python3, `input()` has the desired behavior (always returns `str`).

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same warning on my project.  I'm changing the source code to be py2/3 compatible, and pylint helps a lot.

Running `pylint --py3k` shows only errors about compatibility.

In python 2, if use `filter`, it returns a `list`:

```
>>> my_list = filter(lambda x: x == 1, [1, 1, 2])
>>> my_list
[1, 1]
>>> type(my_list)
<type 'list'>
```

But in python 3, `filter` and other similar methods (`map`, `range`, `zip`, ..) return a iterator, that is incompatible types and perhaps cause bugs in your code.

```
>>> my_list = filter(lambda x: x == 1, [1, 1, 2])
>>> my_list
<filter object at 0x10853ac50>
>>> type(my_list)
<class 'filter'>
```

To make your code python 2/3 compatible, I use a cheat sheet from [python future site](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html)

To avoid this warning, you can use 4 approaches, that works on python 2 and 3:

1 - Using a list comprehension like you said.

2 - Using a `list` function, grant that return always is a materialized list, result is same on both python versions

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x == 1, [1, 1, 2]))
[1, 1]
```

3 - Using `lfilter`, that's a future package import.  It always return a list, uses filter on py2, and `list(filter(..)` on py3.  So, both pythons got the same behaviour and you got a cleaner syntax.

```
>>> from future.utils import lfilter
>>> lfilter(lambda x: x == 1, [1, 1, 2])
[1, 1]
```

4 - The best! Use `filter` always on a loop, this way pylint don't give  warnings, and it have a nice performance boost on python 3.

```
>>> for number in filter(lambda x: x == 1, [1, 1, 2]):
>>>     print(number)
>>> 1
>>> 1
```

Always prefer functions that works on python 3, because python 2 will be retired soon.