# Confused about __str__ on list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, printing, tostring

Coming from a Java background, I understand that `__str__` is something like a Python version of toString (while I do realize that Python is the older language).

So, I have defined a little class along with an `__str__` method as follows:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.neighbours = []
        self.distance = 0


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

I then create a few instances of it:

```
uno = Node(1)    
due = Node(2)    
tri = Node(3)    
qua = Node(4)
```

Now, the expected behaviour when trying to print one of these objects is that it's associated value gets printed. This also happens.

```
print uno
```

yields

```
1
```

But when I do the following:

```
uno.neighbours.append([[due, 4], [tri, 5]])
```

and then

```
print uno.neighbours
```

I get

```
[[[<__main__.Node instance at 0x00000000023A6C48>, 4], [<__main__.Node instance at 0x00000000023A6D08>, 5]]]
```

Where I expected

```
[[2, 4], [3, 5]]
```

What am I missing? And what otherwise cringe-worthy stuff am I doing? :)

Comment: Funny how this was closed 7 years after it was asked.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Python has two different ways to convert an object to a string: `str()` and `repr()`.  Printing an object uses `str()`; printing a list containing an object uses `str()` for the list itself, but the implementation of `list.__str__()` calls `repr()` for the individual items.

So you should also overwrite `__repr__()`.  A simple

```
__repr__ = __str__
```

at the end of the class body will do the trick.

Comment: As `__repr__()` is called when there is no `__str__()`, it is enough to define `__repr__()`.

Comment: `__repr__` should not be set to `__str__` unconditionally. `__repr__` should create a "[representation, that should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__repr__)" In this case, this would rather be `Node(2)` than `2`.

Comment: @trapicki True, though that's more of a guideline rather than a requirement.  The OP wanted the list output mentioned in the question to look like `[[2, 4], [3, 5]]`, and this is what I answered.  It's quite common for types to deviate from the guideline you mentioned, e.g. Numpy's floating point types simply show numbers as representations rather than `numpy.float64(42.0)`, which would become quite verbose in lists.

Comment: I am no python expert, but in this case eval(repr(obj)) won't return the actual node. The answer by @tapicki is a bit closer to truth but lacks the essential part asked by OP. Whoever reads this answer might want to check out https://www.quora.com/What-does-repr-method-mean

Answer (score 44):

Because of the infinite superiority of Python over Java, Python has not *one*, but *two* toString operations.

One is `__str__`, the other is `__repr__`

`__str__` will return a human readable string.
`__repr__` will return an internal representation.

`__repr__` can be invoked on an object by calling `repr(obj)` or by using backticks `` `obj` ``.

When printing lists as well as other container classes, the contained elements will be printed using `__repr__`.

Comment: Note that backticks as shorthand for `repr()` goes away in Python 3.  Minor nit-pick:  Your first sentence is liable to misinterpretation by those who take things too seriously.

Comment: I realize I am courting the possibility of offending the humorically challenged. I thought I did not cross the line. Do you think I should edit my post?

Comment: It's a judgement call.  Probably not.  I just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: It's often difficult to tell the difference between irony and sarcasm -- which may explain why your otherwise acceptable answer hasn't ever received many up-votes. The comment about "humorically challenged" likely didn't help any, either.

Comment: @martineau - No, they are quite easy to discern. Anyway, I think it's a great answer. I think humor should stay legal, and I upvoted it just because of your comment. Thanks!

Comment: @RW77: They indeed can be hard to discern because sarcasm is a form of irony and no one can see you smiling in an all text answer — plus Stackoverlow isn't humor blog. `;¬)`

Answer (score 25):

It provides human readable version  of output rather "Object": Example:

```
class Pet(object):

    def __init__(self, name, species):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getSpecies(self):
        return self.species

    def Norm(self):
        return "%s is a %s" % (self.name, self.species)

if __name__=='__main__':
    a = Pet("jax", "human")
    print a
```

returns

```
<__main__.Pet object at 0x029E2F90>
```

while code with "**str**" return something different

```
class Pet(object):

    def __init__(self, name, species):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getSpecies(self):
        return self.species

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s is a %s" % (self.name, self.species)

if __name__=='__main__':
    a = Pet("jax", "human")
    print a
```

returns:

```
jax is a human
```

Comment: Nice and clear!

Answer (score 12):

### Answer to the question

As pointed out in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12448200/2613492) and as you can read in [PEP 3140](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3140/), `str` on a `list` calls for each item `__repr__`. There is not much you can do about that part.

If you implement `__repr__`, you will get something more descriptive, but if implemented correctly, not exactly what you expected.

### Proper implementation

The **fast, but wrong** solution is to alias `__repr__` to `__str__`.

`__repr__` should not be set to `__str__` *unconditionally*. `__repr__` should create a [representation, that should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value](http://something.com). In this case, this would rather be `Node(2)` than `2`.

A proper implementation of `__repr__` makes it possible to recreate the object. In this example, it should also contain the other significant members, like `neighours` and `distance`.

An *incomplete* example:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, id, neighbours=[], distance=0):
        self.id = id
        self.neighbours = neighbours
        self.distance = distance


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node(id={0.id}, neighbours={0.neighbours!r}, distance={0.distance})".format(self)
        # in an elaborate implementation, members that have the default
        # value could be left out, but this would hide some information


uno = Node(1)    
due = Node(2)    
tri = Node(3)    
qua = Node(4)

print uno
print str(uno)
print repr(uno)

uno.neighbours.append([[due, 4], [tri, 5]])

print uno
print uno.neighbours
print repr(uno)
```

*Note*: `print repr(uno)` together with a proper implementation of `__eq__` and `__ne__` or `__cmp__` would allow to recreate the object and check for equality.

Answer (score 9):

Well, container objects' `__str__` methods will use `repr` on their contents, not `str`. So you could use `__repr__` instead of `__str__`, seeing as you're using an ID as the result.

Answer (score 4):

`__str__` is only called when a *string representation* is required of an object.

For example `str(uno)`, `print "%s" % uno` or `print uno`

However, there is another magic method called `__repr__` this is the *representation* of an object.  When you don't explicitly convert the object to a string, then the *representation* is used.

If you do this `uno.neighbors.append([[str(due),4],[str(tri),5]])` it will do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about classes, and setting unencumbered global variables equal to some value within the class, is that what your global variable stores is actually the reference to the memory location the value is actually stored.

What you're seeing in your output is indicative of this.

Where you might be able to see the value and use print without issue on the initial global variables you used because of the **str** method and how print works, you won't be able to do this with lists, because what is stored in the elements within that list is just a reference to the memory location of the value -- read up on aliases, if you'd like to know more.

Additionally, when using lists and losing track of what is an alias and what is not, you might find you're changing the value of the original list element, if you change it in an alias list -- because again, when you set a list element equal to a list or element within a list, the new list only stores the reference to the memory location (it doesn't actually create new memory space specific to that new variable).  This is where deepcopy comes in handy!

Answer (score -1):

print `self.id.__str__()` would work for you, although not that useful for you.

Your `__str__` method will be more useful when you say want to print out a grid or struct representation as your program develops.

```
print self._grid.__str__()

def __str__(self):
    """
    Return a string representation of the grid for debugging.
    """
    grid_str = ""
    for row in range(self._rows):
        grid_str += str( self._grid[row] )
        grid_str += '\n'
    return grid_str
```