# instance should be capable of printing its components with a method

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can you do this in an object oriented programming python 
what to print what is in the return of **str** method ?

```
class Bike():

    def __str__(self):
        return Components.__str__(self)+", "+ self.getFrameType()

    def printComponents(self):
        print(Bike.self())
```

Answer (score 1):

The `__str__` method is invoked when you want to convert it to string.

```
class Bike():
    def __init__(self):
       self.hello = "hello"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hello + " goodbye"

>>> print(str(Bike()))
"hello goodbye"
```

If you intend to print the object directly i.e. with `print(Bike())` you'll want to use `__repr__` instead. See [Confused about __str__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448175/confused-about-str-in-python) for more details.