# printing __str__ of elements in a list

Tags: python

I've learned that `__str__` can define an output of the string of the object.

Example:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

p1 = Person('Steve Jobs')
p2 = Person('Bill Gates')
p3 = Person('Mark Zuckerberg')

print(p1)  # >>> Steve Jobs
```

it output `Steve Jobs` as I wished, instead of `<__main__.Person object at 0x10410c588>`

However, if I create a list:

```
lst = [p1, p2, p3]
print(lst)
# >>> [<__main__.Person object at 0x1045433c8>, <__main__.Person object at 0x1045434e0>, <__main__.Person object at 0x104543550>]
```

I have to :

```
print([i.__str__() for i in lst])
# >>> ['Steve Jobs', 'Bill Gates', 'Mark Zuckerberg']
```

to make it work??

This does not make sense much, right?

Comment: Look here if it helps -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448175/confused-about-str-in-python

Comment: @AbhinavRisal It helped. thanks!

Comment: `str(i)` is a much better way to spell `i.__str__()`

Comment: @ Eric Thanks! I was kind of stressing the `__str__`, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider implementing:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Person({!r})'.format(self.name)  # !r adds the quotes correctly
```

Which gives:

```
>>> lst
[Person('Steve Jobs'), Person('Bill Gates'), Person('Mark Zuckerberg')]
```

The reason you're seeing mismatching behavior is that `print` calls `str()` on its argument, but `list` `str` and `repr` are the same, and both call `repr` on each element.

Answer (score 2):

The `list.__str__` uses the object's `__repr__` to build the string. So, just delegate `__repr__` to `__str__`:

```
In [1]: class Person(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, name):
   ...:         self.name = name
   ...:     def __str__(self):
   ...:         return self.name
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return str(self)
   ...:
   ...: p1 = Person('Steve Jobs')
   ...: p2 = Person('Bill Gates')
   ...: p3 = Person('Mark Zuckerberg')
   ...:

In [2]: print(p1)
Steve Jobs

In [3]: lst = [p1, p2, p3]
   ...:

In [4]: print(lst)
[Steve Jobs, Bill Gates, Mark Zuckerberg]
```

EDIT

If you want to stick to convention, do somthing like:

```
In [18]: class Person(object):
    ...:     def __init__(self, name):
    ...:         self.name = name
    ...:     def __str__(self):
    ...:         return self.name
    ...:     def __repr__(self):
    ...:         return f"{type(self).__name__}({self.name})"
    ...:

In [19]: p1 = Person('Steve Jobs')

In [20]: print([p1])
[Person(Steve Jobs)]
```

Comment: Thanks. From what I understand repr() is to represent the codes in python so that `eval(repr(i)) = i`.  So is it default that for any python object `__str__ == __repr__`  was made when initiated?

Comment: Correct - output the raw name from `__repr__` goes against the convention. You could output `Person('Steve Jobs')` though, and that would be fine

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 yes, generally you should stick to that convention.

Comment: So if I changed `__repr__` by doing `__repr__ == __str__`, would this cause the `eval(repr(i)) != i`, and will have some impact in the bigger picture?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 unlikely, unless you are relying on using `eval(repr(...))`

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga Got it! Thanks! And I was told that I should avoid using `eval()` almost forever, so I should be fine.

Comment: Note that `__str__ = __repr__` is already the default for objects, so you can get away with just defining `__repr__`. "will have some impact in the bigger picture" - yes, you'll make things harder to debug because the output becomes ambiguous  - what if someone's name is `"Hello, World"`? Now your list of names looks like it has one extra name!