# Use str.join with generator expression in python

Tags: python, call, generator

When I read the question [Python string.join(list) on object array rather than string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497765/python-string-joinlist-on-object-array-rather-than-string-array), I find the following sentence:

```
', '.join(str(x) for x in list)
```

I have already know about `(str(x) for x in list)` is a generator expression, I also know generator is an iterable.  The following code verify the correctness of my view.

```
>>> gen = (x for x in [1,2,3])
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x104349b40>
>>> from collections import Iterable
>>> isinstance(gen, Iterable)
True
```

At the same time, `str.join(iterable)` return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable. So the following works fine as I wish.

```
>>> ",".join((str(x) for x in [1,2,3]))
'123'
```

Then here comes the question, why the code works fine too at bellow, why don't need a parentheses in the function call.

```
', '.join(str(x) for x in [1,2,3])
```

After all,  `str(x) for x in [1,2,3]` itself is not a generator.

```
>>> tmp = str(x) for x in [1,2,3]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    tmp = str(x) for x in [1,2,3]
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was specified when generator expressions were introduced ([PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289)):

> if a function call has a single positional argument, it can be a generator expression without extra parentheses, but in all other cases you have to parenthesize it.

In your case it's a single positional argument, so both ways are possible:

```
', '.join(str(x) for x in [1,2,3])
', '.join((str(x) for x in [1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 2):

After carefully reading the document word by word, I find it's mentioned [Generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

> The parentheses can be omitted on calls with only one argument. See section Calls for the detail.

Answer (score 2):

It's a generator expression either way - but whether enclosing parentheses are *required* depends on the context within which the generator expression appears.  Argument lists are a kind of special case:  if the generator expression is the only argument, then enclosing parentheses aren't required (but can still be used, if you like).  If a call has more than one argument, though, then enclosing parentheses are required.  This is essentially point 2B [in the PEP that introduced this feature](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).