# How convert an array into a binary value using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, binary

I am not sure the reason I am not getting the desired outcome is because I am missing some sort of data type conversion.

I am trying to convert the array of numbers into a binary value.

Input =  [1,1,1,1,0,1]

Desired output= 11101

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of what you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to basically turn the list into a string with a `binary` format? Because your list shows only 1 and 0s or are you expecting other values? `binary = ''.join(Input)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python string.join(list) on object array rather than string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497765/python-string-joinlist-on-object-array-rather-than-string-array)

Comment: That looks like a list, not an array, and while saying that you're converting it _into a binary value_ might technically be correct, I think it misrepresents the question.

Comment: I would edit the title myself in order to make things clearer, but I'm not even sure what the type of the list elements is.